# can't setup:upgrade, stuck in "Invalid XML in file.."

Tags: magento2

I was working on some errors on my site. Now I changed in developer mode and when I try to do `setup:upgrade`, it gives me this error.

No new modules added, working fine till today. Any ideas?

> Running schema recurring...Invalid XML in file /home/r2gutenb/public_html/app/code/Rokanthemes/SlideBanner/etc/acl.xml:
>   Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( acl ).  Line: 2

This is the content of the acl.xml file

[image]

UPDATE1

After deleted the acl.xml files now my homepage gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Well, show us that file so we can pinpoint the mentionned error

Comment: post edited (i can't enter the code in the post, so screenshot)

Comment: Your ACL file is doing nothing. So its better to delete it and try again.

Comment: Ok, now it can upgrade, but now there is an error in homepage... post edited

Comment: It's not correct to have xml file with empty content. You can rename that file to something else and avoid reading from Magento system. Then you will be able to upgrade your database setup

Comment: @MiroslavPetroff, wich file? see edited post, now i have problem with that homepage error

Comment: It seems that you have some invalid `<remove>` tag in your layouts.
Can you check default.xml and cms_index_index.xml files in your theme and custom modules for `<remove>` tags and comment them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to add child tag

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="Rokanthemes_SlideBanner::config_slidebanner" title="SlideBanner" sortOrder="80" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Please add this and check.